# The vue.resource() method and the api.json file

Tags: javascript, web-services, api, vue.js, postman

I'm new to vue.js and I'm confused about what to do next in the program. I want to add a new view page to collect customer information (see code below). I don't know how to write the function after I click the "confirm" button. I think I should go the `DataService.js` file to get the data or update the rules.

Here is the url for the project:

https://coding.net/u/benbenshi/p/vue-admin-test/git

```
// baseConfig.vue 
<template>
  <div class="system-base">
    <el-input type="text">
      <template slot="prepend">userInput:</template>
    </el-input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <el-button @click="somefunction">confirm</el-button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
   import dataservice from '../../services/DataService'
   export default {
     components: {},
     data () {
       return  {}
     },
     computed: {},
     methods: {
        // what should I do here? Should I write some function to handle the confirm event?
      },
    }
</script>
```

Right now I've got an `api.json` file with a structure like this: should I write the function in the `dataServices.js` file based on the API offered in the `api.json` file?

```
//api.json 
{
    "id": "",
    "name": "api",
    "description": "",
    "order": [],
    "folders": [],
    "timestamp": 1234567,
    "owner": "1234567",
    "public": false,
    "requests": [
        // a lot of request api here.
    ]
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can take a reference from the [vue-hackernews-2.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0) code, You can do whatever action you want to do, and than call `this.$router.replace("/your/path")` to redirect to desired page. Here is the stripped code from the [repo](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/master/src/components/ItemList.vue#L90):

```
  methods: {
    loadItems (to = this.page, from = -1) {
      this.loading = true
      this.$store.dispatch('FETCH_LIST_DATA', {
        type: this.type
      }).then(() => {
          this.$router.replace(`/${this.type}/1`)
          return
        this.loading = false
      })
    }
```